Обновления связей в методах CRUD на ASP .NET с использованием СУБД PostgreSQL
возник вопрос нужно ли целенаправленно обновлять связи в методах CRUD в проекте на ASP .NET с использованием СУБД PostgreSQL?
Приведу пример у меня есть сущность "Цех" и "Оборудование" со связью 1 к М. При создании оборудования мне нужно явно указать цеху обновить список оборудования? Или EF Core или PostgreSQL сами сделает это за меня?
Сущность Workshop:
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual List<Machine>? Machines { get; set; }

Сущность Machine:
public int Id { get; set; }
public int WorkshopId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Workshop Workshop{ get; set; }

Метод в контроллере при создание оборудования:
public async Task Create(Machine machine)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    await _machineRepository.Create(machine);
    //Нужно ли обновлять связь тут??
    var entityWS = await _workshopRepository.GetById(machine.WorkshopId);
    if (entityWS != null && entityWS.Machines != null)
    {
     entityWS.Machines.Add(machine);
     await _workshopRepository.Update(entityWS);
    }
    var WS = await _workshopRepository.GetById(machine.WorkshopId);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
  }
  return View(machine);
}


А сами почему не попробовали? )  При создании сущности Machine у неё же WorkshopId задаётся? Ну вот и вся связь. В базу ничего писать дополнительно не нужно. Список Machines, он же в базе не существует, он не настоящий, это просто список сущностей Machine с WorkshopId = Workshop.Id. Другое дело, как сам EF этот список в представлении обновляет, тут я не знаю. Возможно, нужно ему как-то подсказать, что этот виртуальный список обновился в БД и нужно обновить представление. Вопрос интересный.

Я тоже присоединюсь к совету попробовать самому. Просто выполните этот код и проверьте, что получилось. / Вообще, официальные туториалы по ASP.NET + EF на сайте Microsoft вполне хороши. В них показана работа со сложными отношениями.

@AlexanderPetrov А минус ответу от вас, нет? Хотелось бы комментариев, за что минусанули. Тема, конечно, обширная и я слишком категорично подошёл.

@CrazyElf - нет, минус не от меня.

@CrazyElf Сам пробовал, в том и дело, раньше я не задумывался о том нужно ли обновлять или нет. А тут решил поглубже покопается и подумал, что если список машин виртуальный, то и обновлять его нет причин. Лишний код получается, ведь в модели я уже явно указал машине какой у неё цех.
Удалил код который обновляет список и решил посмотреть, что лежит в context. Обратился напрямую к цеху по Id, а он сам создал новый объект и поместил его в этот лист, но кроме этого объекта в листе ничего не было, хотя я точно знаю, что там должны находиться и другие ранее созданные объекты.

Если вы в своих репозиториях _machineRepository и _workshopRepository работаете с БД рекомендованным способом - каждый раз создаёте новый DbContext (и он у вас в DI фреймворке не задан синглтоном):
using(DbContext context = new SomeDbContext())
{
    // Do work with context
}

То вы и так должны получить правильный список Machines когда будете запрашивать Workshop. Ведь это не "настоящий" список, в базе он не хранится, он создаётся EF на основании значений Machine.WorkshopId совпадающих с Workshop.Id. А значение WorkshopId вы, я надеюсь, заполняете, когда создаёте экземпляр Machine.
Если же вы храните и используете один DbContext, то лучше откажитесь от этой практики как можно быстрее. Контекст всё сохраняет в кэше, очень быстро разбухает, не видит обновления базы, сделанные другими процессами, вы от этого ничего не выиграете, но получите случаи неправильного обновления данных, с которыми будет очень непросто разобраться.

Да, к сожалению использую один контекст, руки не доходят переписать. Я ещё только в самом начале пути в ASP.NET, подскажите как было бы правильнее создавать каждый раз новый DbContext? Слышал, что-то про паттерн UnitofWork, но не изучал этот вопрос, он мог бы с этим помочь?

Хотел вставить код, но не понимаю как в комментариях сделать форматирование "блок кода"

@ДмитрийХарченко Нет, в комментарии не нужно код вставлять. Если что-то нужно добавить - добавляйте в вопрос, там всё ок с форматированием. Вообще да, рекомендуется всё время открывать новый контекст, чтобы инфа была всегда актуальная и контекст не распухал лишней инфой. Открытие контекста много времени не занимает, на этом не нужно экономить. Хотя в ASP.NET там свои приколы, возможно там работа с контекстом несколько другая. Кто-то мне поставил минус за ответ, возможно я в чём-то не прав, но в чём - непонятно, никто не прокомментировал этот минус. )

UnitOfWork - да, он про что-то такое как-раз, изучите обязательно.
